# How can I declare a struct of maps as a global variable?

Tags: dictionary, go, struct, initialization, global-variables

In order to declare a global map, I can directly initialize it at creation time:

```
package main

var a = map[string]string{}

func main() {
    a["hello"] = "world"
}
```

How can I initialize a global struct of maps? A similar approach is incorrect:

```
var db struct {
    Users   map[string]User{}
    Entries map[string]Entry{}
}
```

I also tried something like

```
var usersMap = map[string]User{}
var entriesMap = map[string]Entry{}

var db struct {
    Users   usersMap 
    Entries entriesMap 
}
```

but `usersMap` and `entriesMap` are not types.

I would be fine to initialize `db` from within `main()`, provided that it is still global.

Comment: At package level: https://go.dev/play/p/sUYP1afk78p. In main: https://go.dev/play/p/GSPMhr0G8jJ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A struct field declaration expects a type, not a value.  The composite literal expressions   `map[string]User{}` and `map[string]Entry{}` are values, not types.

Fix by separating the field type declarations from the field value initializations:

```
var db = struct {
    Users   map[string]User
    Entries map[string]Entry
}{
    Users:   map[string]User{},
    Entries: map[string]Entry{},
}
```